# How can I iterate this loop properly?

Tags: python

I have 2 list in my program and what im trying to do is to set list 1 as the starting point and list 2 as ending point for a range of lines. The range of lines is where I will search for the error string.

```
list1 = [ '1' , '9',  '15']
list2 = [ '7' , '12',  '22']
```

and this is what i have for now

```
for startLine, endLine in zip(list1, list2):
    print(startLine, endLine) #output here is  1 7, 9 12, 15 22
    for line in lines[startLine:endLine]:
         if 'error ' in line:
             line = line.rstrip()
             search_results.append(line)
```

However , when the 2nd for loop runs, the lines repeat multiple times and i only need to search each range once for the 'error' string

Comment: Does adding a `break` inside your `if` solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a break will do that:

```
for startLine, endLine in zip(list1, list2):
    print(startLine, endLine) #output here is  1 7, 9 12, 15 22
    for line in lines[startLine:endLine]:
         if 'error ' in line:
             line = line.rstrip()
             search_results.append(line)
             break                                  # this will terminate out of the inner loop as soon as an the condition is met
```

Comment: Also on my given loop there are multiple lines that has error string but my program only shows the first hit of the string even though i put it in a for loop condition, can you see what am i doing wrongly ?

Comment: Umm, I don't get what you are trying to say. Are you saying that you want all the positions where "error" appears in the string `line`?

Comment: Yes for example for the range line 1 to line 7 , I want to get all the lines containing the string but when I run my program it only shows the first time where the string is found even though I used the for loop condition

Comment: Then you should use your original code, which doesn't break after the first occurrence of the string. If you find it helpful, you can create a temporary array in which you would append the required lines, and then after the whole for loop is done, append this temporary array to the main answer array, so you would get structured output for each range.